# Controller for views in a state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to define a controller within an abstract state so that I can have a single controller for all my views but the functions inside controller are not getting called if the controller is defined outside.

```
.state('update', {
        url : '/update',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        controller : function($scope) {   //works
            $scope.hello = function() {
                alert("hello");
            }
        }
        controller : 'updateController'  // Doesn't work
    })
    .state('update.detail', {
        url : '/view/:id',
        views : {
            "" : {
                templateUrl : 'update-detail.html'
            },

            "header@update.detail" : {
                templateUrl : 'header.html'
            },
            "genericnavigation@update.detail" : {
                templateUrl : 'generic-navigation.html'
            },
            "mnavigation@update.detail" : {
                templateUrl : 'mobile-navigation.html'
            },
            "updatecontent@update.detail" : {
                templateUrl : 'update-content.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

HTML

```
header.html
 <div ng-click="hello();"></div>  //Click event doesn't get fired for ( controller : 'updateController' )


app.controller('updateController', ['$scope', '$state', function($state, $scope) {
 console.log("inside update")
 $scope.hello = function() {
        alert("hello");
 }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how you defined your controller:

```
['$scope', '$state', function($state, $scope)
```

The arguments are not in the right order. So the $state variable is in fact the scope, and the $scope variable is in fact the state.